# mongodb find all slow

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new with nodejs and mongodb. I have a simple request which will return 800 entities without any where statements. Just find all. or explain();
Very slow responder.....

Is there a more better way to do collection.find().lean() ?

```
const Jobs = require("../model/Jobs.mongo");

const saveData = async (title, link, location, idJob, companyName) => {
  const found = await Jobs.findOne({ idJob: idJob });
  if (!found) {
    try {
      const job = new Jobs({
        title: title,
        link: link,
        location: location,
        idJob: idJob,
        companyName: companyName,
      });
      await job.save();
      console.log(job);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(`${title} ***** is already in the data with id ***** ${idJob}`);
  }
};

const getAllJobs = async (req, res) => {
  const jobs = await Jobs.find({}).sort({ createdAt: "desc" }).lean();
  res.status(200).json({ jobs, count: jobs.length });
};

const getJobByCompany = async (req, res) => {
  const {
    params: { companyName: companyName },
  } = req;

  const job = await Jobs.find({
    companyName: companyName,
  });
  if (!job) {
    res.status(404).json({});
  }
  res.status(200).json({ job, count: job.length });
};

module.exports = {
  saveData,
  getAllJobs,
  getJobByCompany,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue for a while try to check you internet connection.

You can also take a look how much is the data that you want to receive.

It can be just from a internet speed drop, let me know what is the result :)

Comment: It happens from another computer different internet  too...

Comment: have you tried from a local DB mongodb Campass?
and one more thing  - what is the response time

Comment: but anyway I think it's too much to request 800 records from the DB
maybe a pagination will work good 
as long as I don't know what you want to do I can't help more.

Comment: How do I check response time? I think something like a minute

Comment: You can try postman

Comment: time:3.42 s size:560.90kb

Comment: well this is a lot for a single request, but anyway it should not be that slow
the request looks fine to me.
Also I can't say that using  .lean() is a bad practice if it works it's ok

Best regards :)